# Is there a drop-table equivalence in google.cloud.datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am learning `google.cloud.datastore` at the moment, but I couldn't find a method to drop a table/kind in `google.cloud.datastore.Client`. I am wondering is there an equivalent way to do this. Or I just need to `delete_multi` keys retrieved for a particular `kind`, using `query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to use Cloud Dataflow to delete entities in bulk:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/bulk-delete

Comment: Not with a single method call, but you can do a keys-only query for the kind you want to delete, and then delete the results one batch at a time.